# How to get information document by _id using quickmongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, discord.js

How to get information document by _id using quickmongo [MongoDB]?  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```js
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId; 
var o_id = new ObjectId(id);
db.test.find({_id:o_id});
```